# How do you make this fade in effect work properly?

Tags: javascript, scroll, onload

I am trying to complete a challenge by adding an effect where I have my name appear onload, and then disappear on scroll. The only issue is that I can only see if when I scroll down and scroll back up. I know exactly where the issue is, but because I got this code from somewhere else, I am not too sure how to work with it.
In the if statement, there is a the parameter window.scrollY>500. I know I have to change the number to a different value, but I am not sure how to determine what number to change it to. Could someone better explain to me what this exactly means, and how to determine what value to make it so I can better understand for future reference?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

```js
window.onload = function() {
    const EFFECT = document.getElementById('headingName');

    window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollEffect);
    function scrollEffect() {
        if(window.scrollY>500) {
            EFFECT.style.opacity = '1';
            EFFECT.style.transform = 'translateX(0px)';
            EFFECT.style.transition = '1s ease-in-out';
        }
        else {
            EFFECT.style.opacity = '0';
            EFFECT.style.transform = 'translateX(-50px)';
        }
    }
    scrollEffect();
}
```

```html
  <h1 id='headingName'>Alex Schmidt</h1>
```

Comment: Do you have to use JS only? Toggling a class which applies styles from CSS is generally a more maintainable approach.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using CSS and simply toggling the style using a class:

I have added a bit of extra styling and filler text to make the example functional, these bits are noted in the code.

I think the reason your version wasn't working was due to the `transition` being set as your tried to trigger the effect, the transition needs to exist before the style is changed. That means that the first time you reach the 500 point (That 500 simply means you are scrolled 500 pixels down the page), there is no transition set, and the styles will be applied immediately.

In the CSS below you can see that the transition is set on `#headingName`, and is therefor always applied to the element, whether it's currently visible or not (Which means that the transition is shown for both showing and hiding)

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const EFFECT = document.getElementById('headingName');

  window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollEffect);

  function scrollEffect() {
    if (window.scrollY > 500) {
      EFFECT.classList.add("show");
    } else {
      EFFECT.classList.remove("show");
    }
  }
  scrollEffect();
}
```

```css
#headingName {
  /* This is just to make the example functional */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  
  /* This is the important bit */
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50px);
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}

#headingName.show {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0px);
}

/* This is just so that the page is scrollable and the example works */
#fillerText {
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1 id='headingName'>Alex Schmidt</h1>
<div id='fillerText'>
  Filler text Filler text Filler text Filler text Filler text Filler text Filler text Filler text Filler text Filler text Filler text Filler text Filler text Filler text Filler text Filler text Filler text Filler text Filler text Filler text Filler text Filler text Filler text Filler text Filler text Filler text Filler text Filler text Filler text Filler text Filler text Filler text Filler text Filler text Filler text Filler text Filler text Filler text Filler text Filler text Filler text Filler text Filler text Filler text Filler text
</div>
```

Comment: I am also trying to make it fade in on load as well, should I added this in a different function, or within the same one?

Comment: @A.D.Schmidt I think your call to `scrollEffect()` inside the `window.onload` should already be doing that bit for you (Though you would still have to be more than 500 pixels down the page for that to have a visible effect)